# pseudopolynomial time and polynomial time

Tags: algorithm

I am confused about the pseudopolynomial time in compare to polynomial time

```
input(n);
for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
     doStuff; }
```

The runtime would be `O(n)` but  writing out the number n takes `x=O(log n)` bits.

So, if we let x be the number of bits required to write out the input n, the runtime of this algorithm is actually `O(2^x)`, which is not a polynomial in x.
Is this conclusion correct?

Edit: Look at simple primetest.

```
  function isPrime(n):
  for i from 2 to n - 1:
     if (n mod i) = 0, return false
  return true
```

The runtime would be `O(n)`. But  remember, the formal definition of time complexity talks about the complexity of the algorithm as a function of the number of bits of input.

Therefore, if we let x be the number of bits required to write out the input n, the runtime of this algorithm is actually O(2^x), which is not a polynomial in x.

EDIT2: i got all your points but look at Knapsack problem.
     // Input:

```
 // Values (stored in array v)

// Weights (stored in array w)

// Number of distinct items (n)

 // Knapsack capacity (W)


 for j from 0 to W do:

m[0, j] := 0


 for i from 1 to n do:

for j from 0 to W do:

    if w[i] > j then:

        m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]

    else m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
```

if you guys are right it would mean that  Knapsack problem has runtime `o(n*W)`, therefore it has  polynomial time !

Answer (score 1):

Alex does `64` push-ups everyday.

and

Alex does `2^6` push-ups everyday.

If above two lines mean same to you, then `O(n)` and `O(2^x)` doesn't matter :)

```
O(2^x)

=> O(2^log_2(n))

=> n [as we know x^log_x(y) = y]
```

> The formal definition of time complexity talks about the complexity of
>   the algorithm as a function of the number of bits of input.

Yes, you're right. But the idea of Big-O analysis is about the growth rate of algorithm with growth of input, not the precise counting of exactly how many times my loop iterates.

As for example, when `n = 32`, the algorithm complexity is `O(2^5)`, but with growth of `n`, for example when `n = 1048576`, the complexity will be `O(2^20)`. So, complexity increases with input increases.

`n` or `2^(log_2(n))` are all about presenting same numeric amount differently. As long as the growth rate of the algorithm is linearly proportional to the growth rate of input, the algorithm is linear - no matter whether we represent the input `n` as `e^x` or `log(y)`.

## Edit

Quoted from Wikipedia

> The `O(nW)` complexity does not contradict the fact that the knapsack
>   problem is NP-complete, since `W`, unlike `n`, is not polynomial in
>   the length of the input to the problem. The length of the `W` input to
>   the problem is proportional to the number of bits in `W`, `log W`, not
>   to `W` itself.

You  first two snippet was about to `n` which has obviously polynomial growth.

Comment: [PrimeTest has not polynomial time](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-pseudo-polynomial-time-complexity-I-saw-that-Knapsack-runs-in-pseudo-polynomial-time-I-read-about-this-here-Pseudo-polynomial-time-but-I-am-not-able-to-follow-I-want-to-understand-the-concept-of-pseudo-polynomial-running-time-and-how-knapsack-runs-in-pseudo-polynomial-time/answer/Nishanth-Dikkala)

Answer (score 0):

Since,
`x = ceil(log_2(n))`, `2^x` becomes `2^log_2(n)`, which is nothing but `n` (using `a^log_a(b) = b`).

Remember to analyse the runtime of an algorithm only in the terms of your input variables, and not doing something fancy like counting the bits it would require, since (in this case, for example) the number of bits itself is a logarithm of the number!